# How to format large price value in Milion or Billion, Using Select statement

Tags: php, mysql

In DB I have value of price in numbers but I want to select price as 8.3M if it is 830000 and 5B if it is 5000000?

```
SELECT (CASE
WHEN price_col >= 1000000 THEN CONCAT(price_col,'B')
WHEN price_col >= 100000 THEN CONCAT(price_col,'M')
WHEN price_col >= 1000 THEN CONCAT(price_col,'K')
ELSE price_col END) as new_price_col
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CASE` clause to differential which Unit need to be displayed.

For example:

```
SELECT (CASE
WHEN price_col >= 1000000 THEN CONCAT(price_col/100000,'B')
WHEN price_col >= 100000 THEN CONCAT(price_col/100000,'M')
WHEN price_col >= 1000 THEN CONCAT(price_col/1000,'K')
ELSE price_col END) as new_price_col
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT (CASE WHEN length(price)=9 THEN CONCAT(price/100000,'M')

ELSE (CASE WHEN lenght(price)=10 THEN CONCAT(price/1000000,'B' END) END) AS price